# KnockoutJS obfuscation: is there any tool that does so automatically?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Is here any tool to obfuscate and compile a KnockoutJS page?

My project mainly has pages like this:

```
<p data-bind="text: property_name"></p>

<script>
class MyView(){ 
    constructor(){
        this.property_name = ko.observable("Hello, world");
    }
}
ko.applyBindings(new MyView());
</script>
```

I need something that will automatically compile something like above into the most unreadable thing.

The tools I've found will compile the JavaScript only and leave things like `MyView` and `property_name` unaltered (and rightfully so, otherwise the `data-bind` would need to change as well).

JS compilers will not look into the HTML.

Is there something that can also search inside of the `data-bind`s?

Comment: Last time I checked, there weren't. My team eventually ended up writing a custom HTML build job that takes in JS source maps + views and parses the data-bind attributes to inject the new variable names. We also ended up having to do some weird tricks to prevent dead code removal for props only used inside view code. All in all, in retrospect, I'd say it isn't worth the trouble...